# How do I check if two Objects are equal in terms of their properties only without breaking the existing Object.Equals()?

Tags: c#, object, equals, hashcode

Basically, GethashCode is different even though they contain the SAME values for the properties... so why is the default to return diff hashcodes?

```
public class User
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public String Username { get; set; }
}

User a = new User();
a.Id = 1;
a.Username = "Hello";

User b = new User();
b.Id = 1;
b.Username = "Hello";

Console.WriteLine("Hash A: {0} | Hash B: {1}", a.GetHashCode(), b.GetHashCode());
//Hash A: 37121646 | Hash B: 45592480 <-- these values change each time I rerun the app?
```

Is there a more proper way to make it so I don't break how Object.Equals works for my objects, but am still able to have my own equality checking based on the parameter values?

The reason I ask is because I have a service: `SynchronizeUsers()` which downloads an array of users. Instead of clearing out my cache of users, I'd rather just update the ones that need to be updated, remove the ones that the synch says to, and add the new ones. But, I can't just do Object.Equals() on these objects.

Comment: It's normal for the hash codes to change over application runs. What is *not* normal is that `a.GetHashCode() != b.GetHashCode()` -- whoever wrote that class made it buggy, unless the class has important members that get automatically initialized to a non-fixed value (e.g. `DateTime.Now`).

Comment: Also, what is the question here? (a) How to make `Equals` return true, or (b) something related to `GetHashCode`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Have you tried implementing your own IEqualityComparer? You can pass this to an .Equals() overload to define your own custom equality logic, as in

User A = User B even if they are distinct instances, if properties x, y, z are the same.

See this:
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx)

Edit: I should have written you can instantiate your EqualityComparer and pass two instances to its Equals() method and get a bool. Basic console app... will show true, false, false. Thing is trivial, has the two properties shown.

```
var comparer = new ThingEqualityComparer();

Console.WriteLine(comparer.Equals(new Thing() { Id = 1, Name = "1" }, new Thing() { Id = 1, Name = "1" }));
Console.WriteLine(comparer.Equals(new Thing() { Id = 1, Name = "1" }, new Thing() { Id = 2, Name = "2" }));
Console.WriteLine(comparer.Equals(new Thing() { Id = 1, Name = "1" }, null));


class ThingEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Thing>
{
    public bool Equals(Thing x, Thing y)
    {
        if (x == null || y == null)
            return false;

        return (x.Id == y.Id && x.Name == y.Name);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Thing obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1  This is a valid way to go, but it does introduce a lot of unnecessary code.

Comment: You are right that it introduces more code, but as ebyrob's comment indicates, best practice is to override GetHashCode() anyway and IEqualityComparer only has the two methods Equals() and GetHashCode() to override. Personally I prefer separating out this sort of "business logic"; a separate comparer also lends itself to IoC... but in the end overriding Equals() would work fine too.

Comment: @Nix: If this code is needed to implement the application's business logic, then I would call it **most necessary**.

Comment: @Jon agreed, but its not the only way, and this way uses more code then simply using extensions.

Comment: Why would you add a custom IEqualityComparer for a class that doesn't yet have it's own default equality comparison when there is one obvious equality comparison for the data set?

Comment: @ebyrob, the OP @michael said for whatever reason he does not want to or cannot use object.Equals(). So an IEqualityComparer does what he needs. For me, I also looked at his scenario and thought this way would give him future flexibility to new up comparers based on context - i.e. IoC - rather than "hard-coding" the equality logic right in the object; though he did not of course ask for this.

Comment: I just posted an answer for how ReSharper can do this automatically, just FYI. :-)

Comment: In case `x` and `y` are `null`. Both. Does this mean not equality?

Comment: @demo null is not equal to null. Think about null as unknown or non-existent.

Answer (score 44):

Too late to answer, but someone might end up here and I need to know my idea is right or wrong.
If strictly values are the consideration, then why not make the objects JSON and compare the JSON strings? Like:

```
if (JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj1) == JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj2)) continue;
```

Comment: Best answer, since it's allow the code to have dynamic objects.

Comment: So simple but so smart

Answer (score 14):

If you have ReSharper installed (it's worth it!) then all you have to do is:

```
Alt+Insert
```

With your cursor inside the class. A partial class is good for hiding the boilerplate.

It'll automatically implement an equality check for each property.

(Select all properties w/ Ctrl+A, and you can check all w/ Space!)

Answer (score 3):

It is recommended to over-ride GetHashCode() when over-riding GetEquals().

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

e.g.

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return this.Username.GetHashCode() * this.Id;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that does not require any custom logic in the class and uses generics to ensure both arguments (obj1 and obj2) are the same type at compile time:

```
  public static class ObjectComparerUtility
  {
    public static bool ObjectsAreEqual<T>(T obj1, T obj2)
    {
      var obj1Serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj1);
      var obj2Serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj2);

      return obj1Serialized == obj2Serialized;
    }
  }
```

Usage:

```
  var c1 = new ConcreteType { Foo = "test1" };
  var c2 = new ConcreteType { Foo = "test1" };
  var areEqual = ObjectComparerUtility.ObjectsAreEqual(c1, c2);
  Assert.IsTrue(areEqual);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not write your own Equality method? ie,

```
User a = new User();
a.Id = 1;
a.Username = "Hello";
User b = new User();
b.Id = 1;
b.Username = "Hello";
a.IsEqualTo(b);
```

where IsEqualTo is defined within your user class as:

```
Public bool IsEqualTo(user compareTo)
{
  return (UserName == compareTo.UserName && Id == compareTo.Id);
}
```

Comment: I just posted an answer for how ReSharper can do this automatically, just FYI. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to hash things look into using an extension method, to generate the hash.

```
public static int GenerateHash(this User myUser){
    return myUser.UserName.GetHashCode() ^ ... other properties....
}
```

Then in your code you could do:

```
Console.WriteLine("Hash A: {0} | Hash B: {1}", a.GenerateHash(), b.GenerateHash());
```

This would leave everything intact, and should not break anything else.   If you are looking for a way to compare objects, you could do the same using an extension method:

```
public static int AreEqual(this User myUser, User someOther){
    return myUser.UserName == someOther.UserName && ...  other properties.
}
```

Usage would be like:

```
if(a.AreEqual(b)){
    // these are equal have fun.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

provided code defines a Person class with FirstName and LastName properties. The class overrides the Equals and GetHashCode methods, which are used for comparing objects and generating hash codes for objects, respectively.

The Equals method compares two Person objects by checking if they are of the same type and have the same FirstName and LastName values. If any of these conditions are not met, the method returns false. Otherwise, it returns true.

The GetHashCode method generates a hash code for a Person object by combining the hash codes of its FirstName and LastName properties using a hash code calculation algorithm. This is necessary for using Person objects in hash-based collections like dictionaries or hash sets.

This implementation of Equals and GetHashCode is generally correct and adheres to the guidelines for overriding these methods. It ensures that two Person objects are considered equal if they have the same FirstName and LastName values. Additionally, the hash code calculation is based on the same properties, providing consistent behavior for hash-based collections.

```
public class Person
{
       public string FirstName { get; set; }
       public string LastName { get; set; }
   
       public override bool Equals(object obj)
       {
           if (obj == null || GetType() != obj.GetType())
           {
               return false;
           }
   
           Person otherPerson = (Person)obj;
   
           return FirstName == otherPerson.FirstName && LastName == otherPerson.LastName;
       }
   
       public override int GetHashCode()
       {
           int hashCode = 17;
           hashCode = hashCode * 23 + FirstName.GetHashCode();
           hashCode = hashCode * 23 + LastName.GetHashCode();
           return hashCode;
       }
}
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/34430642) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Add a method:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    public bool IsUser(object obj) 
    {
        return (obj is User && ((User)obj).UserID == this.UserID);
    }
}
```

Comment: -1: This is a terrible idea because it doesn't take the relationship between `Equals` and `GetHashCode` into account. Also, it only works if you can modify the class.

Comment: Why does it need to take `GetHashCode()` into account? Did I miss something? `a.GetHashCode() == b.GetHashCode()` is always false when `a` and `b` are separate object instances IIRC.

Comment: @FlyingStreudel: That's not correct. The contract is that when two objects compare as equal, their hashcodes **must** also be equal. Your solution changes the result of the equality comparison, but does not make sure that when it returns `true` the hashcodes will also be equal. [Aside: that `a` and `b` are separate object instances tells us exactly nothing about their hashcodes]

Comment: @Jon - He's using an array, not hashing, but that is true. [Aside: If you don't implement your own `GetHashCode()` I don't think it is guaranteed to be equal unless they are the same instance]

Comment: @FlyingStreudel: I don't see any arrays in that code. Also, the documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx) agrees with me: *"If two objects compare as equal, the GetHashCode method for each object must return the same value. However, if two objects do not compare as equal, the GetHashCode methods for the two object do not have to return different values."*

Comment: @Jon - *The reason I ask is because I have a service: SynchronizeUsers() which downloads an array of users* Also, I agreed with you, but what you just posted is exactly what I said... Two objects that do not compare as equal (i.e. two separate instances) can have the same hash but are not guaranteed to. You would have to implement your own `GetHashCode()` to ensure that.

Comment: @FlyingStreudel: This: *"a.GetHashCode() == b.GetHashCode() is always false when a and b are separate object instances"* (no, they *can* have equal hash codes even if completely unrelated) is not the same as this: *"I don't think it is guaranteed to be equal unless they are the same instance"* (correct is *unless they compare as equal*) and not the same as this: *"Two objects that do not compare as equal can have the same hash but are not guaranteed to"* (which is correct).

Comment: @Jon - Dudeski, it all started with an IIRC, after which I refreshed my memory and I agree with you. I was just saying if you make a brand-new simple object and create two instances of it, they aren't guaranteed to have the same hash. That would be with a standard `.Equals()` and standard `.GetHashCode()`

Comment: @FlyingStreudel: I don't expect anyone to memorize all of MSDN. The answer above is still problematic though.

Comment: @Jon - I changed it, unless I missed something this time around too?

Comment: @FlyingStreudel: Downvote removed. However, as a last comment, you might want to rethink the *use Equals() for reference comparison* part. It's not a reference comparison (usually).

Answer (score -3):

The string array is the exclude list for the compare. It uses reflection but the performance is very good. Please check apache commons lang 3 library

```
CompareToBuilder.reflectionCompare(arg0, arg1, new String[]{"UID", "uidcount"})
```