# How to check if properties across objects in a list are equal?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have two objects in a list and want to ensure that all properties of these objects are having the same value.

For example:

```
List<Person> persons = new List<Person>
{
    new Person { Id = "1", Name = "peter" },
    new Person { Id = "1", Name = "peter" }
};
```

Now I want to get `true` as both objects properties are same. I have tried with the following lambda expression.

```
var areEqual = persons.All(o => o == persons.First());
```

but I'm getting `false` in `areEqual`. I'm unable to understand why this is so and want to know how to do it correctly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if two Objects are equal in terms of their properties only without breaking the existing Object.Equals()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413108/how-do-i-check-if-two-objects-are-equal-in-terms-of-their-properties-only-withou)

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine no sir.

Comment: By doing `o => o == persons.First()` you're checking to see whether `o` and `persons[0]` are the same object. In C#, by default, objects are only the same if they point to the same instance in memory, i.e if the reference to those objects are the same. I guess what you're looking is *value* equality, i.e two objects are the same if all they're properties/ fields are the same. Sadly, by default, C# doesn't have this without abusing serialization or changing your classes to either a `struct` or a `record`

Answer (score 5):

You can find out if all elements are the same by using:

```
persons.Distinct().Count() == 1
```

If it's zero there were no entries in the first place, if it's greater 1, you had entries that were not the same.

Now... how do you make sure the `.Distinct()` call knows when two objects are the same?

- Option 1: `Person` is already a `record`. Great. Inbuilt funtionality. Done.
- Option 2: `Person` implements `IEquatable<Person>` and it does the check you want.
- Option 3: `Person` overrides `Object.Equals` and `Object.GetHashCode` on it's own, in a way you need.
- Option 4: `Person` is neither of the above and you don't want to change it to check one of those boxes. Then you can still implement your own `IEqualityComparer<Person>` and pass an instance of it to the distinct method like this:

  ```
  persons.Distinct(new MyCustomPersonEqualityComparer()).Count() == 1
  ```

Comment: I'd highly recommend implementing an `IEqualityComparer<Person>` and using that over implementing `IEquatable<Person>`, as the `IEquatable` interface is quite a bit trickier to implement that what one would think

Answer (score 3):

This query would be meaningless if you have less than 2 items. So, take first element to compare to the rest

```
var allAreSame = persons
    .All(p => p.Id == persons[0].Id && p.Name == persons[0].Name);
```

Or (faster way)

```
var allAreSame = !persons
    .Any(p => p.Id != persons[0].Id || p.Name != persons[0].Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Person` is a reference type, the default == is performing memory's location equality check. In order to perform your own equality check you must implement `IComparable<Person>`.

You can also use `record` instead of `class`, this implements behind the hoods the equality checks on the record's public properties.

```cs
public record Person
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```