# Method is only returning null. Searchs class list if user input equals what the user has inputed return the input else return null isn't working

Tags: c#, .net, oop

as said in the title I have a class list on everytime that the program lauches it reads a txt file and the info the txt file gets changed into objects of that class (this works without a issue), but when I want to verify that what a user has input is equaled to something in this class list it doesn't seem to return the proper value but instead only every returns null. I can't seem to figure out why, I suppose I could maybe change the class list to a string list and verify via that way but kinda seems not the proper thing to do. I will provide code below. Some ideas would be helpful!

clientaccount is meant to be the input,
clientaccounts is the class list. If it doesn't contain it return null.

```
  public Client? GetAccountAccountsE(ClientEmail cliEmail)
    {

        foreach (Client clientaccount in clientaccounts)
        {
            
            if (clientaccount.Equals(cliEmail)) { return clientaccount; Console.WriteLine("returning account"); }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("nulling");
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if two Objects are equal in terms of their properties only without breaking the existing Object.Equals()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413108/how-do-i-check-if-two-objects-are-equal-in-terms-of-their-properties-only-withou)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing `Client` to `ClientEmail`, which are, unless you override the `Equals()`-method, not equal.

If `ClientEmail email` is a property of `Client`, try:

```
 if (clientaccount.email.Equals(cliEmail)) { 
   Console.WriteLine("returning account");
   return clientaccount;
 }
```

Comment: ClientEmail is a derived class of Client which is the base class.

Comment: You didn't mention that. IMO, that's a very weird use-case for inheritance. Please provide both classes.

Comment: sorry was very late when I posted this problem, fixed by making a new class and not using equals()

Comment: `public Client GetAccountAccountsE(ClientEmail cliEmail)
        {
            foreach (Client clientaccount in clientaccounts)
            {
                if (clientaccount.MatchesEmail(cliEmail)) { return clientaccount; }
            }
           
            return null;
        }`

Comment: `public bool MatchesEmail(ClientEmail clientemail)
        {
            if (Clientemail.UserClientEmail == clientemail.UserClientEmail) return true;
            return false;
        }`

Comment: As far as I see, you don't use new classes, but methods. Other than that, that's basically what I proposed. I can give you a tip: Use proper naming. This makes it easier for you and everyone else to understand your code.