# How to properly compare two complex objects in C#

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I want to figure out the best way to check whether two objects are equal.

My case: If "Street's" name is equal to "StandardStreet's" name or one of "StandardStreet's" synonyms' name, then return true;

```
 public class BaseStreet
 {
     [Key]
     [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
     public int Id { get; set; } 

     public string Name { get; set; }
 }
```

```
public class Street : BaseStreet
{
 
}
```

```
 public class SynonymStreet : BaseStreet 
 {

     public int StandardStreetId { get; set; }
     [ForeignKey("StandardStreetId")]

     public StandardStreet StandardStreet { get; set; } 
    
 }
```

```
  public class StandardStreet  : BaseStreet
  {

      public HashSet<SynonymStreet> SynonymStreets { get; set; }

//I think the logic will be here
      public override bool Equals(object? obj)
      {
          if (obj == null || obj.GetType() != typeof(BaseStreet))
          {
              return false;
          }
          else
          {
              Street street = (Street)obj;
              return street.CityId == CityId && (Name.Equals(street.Name) || SynonymStreets.Select(x => x.Name).Contains(street.Name));
          }
          
      }

  }
```

I want to check whether Street (by name) is equal to StandardStreet according description above?
It would be nice to use Contains method (as I know it also uses Equals method)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if two Objects are equal in terms of their properties only without breaking the existing Object.Equals()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413108/how-do-i-check-if-two-objects-are-equal-in-terms-of-their-properties-only-withou), [Best way to compare two complex objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10454519/8017690)

Comment: Note that the cast to `Street` in `Equals` is wrong here, because you've tested that obj must be _exactly_ `BaseStreet`.

Comment: The cyclic dependency: Is it intentional? (`StandardStreet` has many `SynonymStreets` which in turn have one `StandardStreet` ... )

Comment: @YongShun I also thought about IEqualityComparer. But it must accept base class which doesn't have some properties of its child class. What if I use simple linq Where condition?

Comment: @PMF Yes, It is just an attempt to solve)

Answer (score 1):

Ok so to me it seems like you already got a decent base/setup. The only changes that come to my mind are

```cs
public override bool Equals(object? obj)
{
    
    if(obj is not null && obj is BaseStreet baStr)
    {
        return baStr.CityId == CityId && (Name == baStr.Name || SynonymStreets.Any(s => s.Name == baStr.Name));
    }else
    {
        return false;
    }
 
}
```

Although since you Posted this id like to know what Problems you ran into. Or is this just a question of "how do I make this more efficient"?